# comparing string and variable but failing based on contains

Tags: c#

What I have going on is I have two files.  Both files are delimited by '|'.  If file 1 matches a line in file 2 I need to combine the lines.  Here is the code:

```
   string[] mathlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\math.txt");
   var addlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"K:\add.txt");
   foreach (string ml in mathlines)
   {
       string[] parse = ml.Split('|');
       if (addlines.Contains(parse[0]))
       {
           File.AppendAllText(@"C:\final.txt", parse[0]+"|"+parse[1]+"\n");
       }
       else
       {
           File.AppendAllText(@"C:\final.txt", ml + "\n");
       }
   }
```

I realize that the math part isn't setup yet, but I need to get the match part working.

Here is an example:

mathlines:

```
dart|504.91  
GI|1782.06  
Gcel|194.52  
clay|437.35  
grado|217.77  
greGCR|14.82  
rp|372.54  
rp2|11.92  
gsg|349.92  
GSxil|4520.55
```

addlines:

```
Gimet|13768994304  
GSxil|394735896576  
Ho|4994967296  
gen|485331304448  
GSctal|23482733690  
Obr|88899345920
```

As you can see mathlines contains GSxil and so does addlines but my `if (addlines.Contains)` never fines the variable in addlines.  Any help is always loved!  Thanks.

Sorry forgot to mention that I need it to match exactly on the comparison.  Also i need to split out the variable on the correct line that matches. So I would need to split out the 394735896576 this example and then append the 394735896576.

Comment: Code work fine for me. 
Is K:\add.txt are right path?

Comment: Does not the if else blocks do the same thing?

Comment: the else block is suppose to be for anything that fails, it works as intended.

Comment: I really can't follow. What can fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addLines.Contains(parse[0])` is going to match on the entire string; you need to match based on part. There are more efficient solutions, but a O(n^2) option is to use LINQ `Any()`:

```
if (addLines.Any(l => l.StartsWith(parse[0])))
{
...
```

Comment: That sort of works but it isnt precise enough of the comparison for example, the GSxil matches GSxil_qwe2 and should just match the GSxil.

Comment: Also, how do i write out the exact varible line?  meaning if variable 3 was the match i need to write out the split[1] of it.

Comment: I would probably build a dictionary from addLines based on splitting each line at the |. Then you could just look up the key in the dictionary and use its value however you want. It's easier to answer specific questions if you show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could load all lines from addlines.txt into a dictionary and then use that to find a match for each line in mathlines.txt. This method would be much faster than what you have currently.

```
string[] mathlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\math.txt");
string[] addlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"K:\addlines.txt");
string[] finallines = new string[mathlines.Length];
var addlinesLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < addlines.Length; i++)
{
  string[] parts = addlines[i].Split('|');
  if (parts.Length == 2) // Will there ever be more than 2 parts?
  {
    addlinesLookup.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < mathlines.Length; i++)
{
  string[] parts = mathlines[i].Split('|');
  if (parts.Length >= 1)
  {
    if (addlinesLookup.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
    {
      finallines[i] = mathlines[i] + "|" + addlinesLookup[parts[0]] + "\n";
    }
    {
      finallines[i] = mathlines[i] + "\n";
    }
  }
}
File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\final.txt", finallines, Encoding.ASCII);
```